# Creating user initials as a computed observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So i am looking into created a computed observable that will take the first letter of the `first name` and first letter of the `last name` and create an `initials` observable.

```
self.firstName = ko.observable(data.firstName);
self.lastName = ko.observable(data.lastName);
self.initials = ko.pureComputed(function(){return...});
```

what is the proper way to get the first letter for each of the name variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to use `charAt(index)` on observable(string) to get the first character .

**viewModel:**

```
var ViewModel = function (firstname, lastname) {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable(firstname);
    self.lastName = ko.observable(lastname);
    self.initials = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return self.firstName().charAt(0) + ' '+ self.lastName().charAt(0); 
    });
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Beckham", "David"));
```

sample working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26444/)**

Check the docs **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)** as you can apply it on `string`